# How to programmatically assign two different classes to one variable?

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game in Unity and I have 2 classes, I want to assign that variable with 2 different classes depending on a boolean value, to later use that class how I wish, here is the code I have so far to give an idea what im looking for, is it even possible for it to be done? Thanks

```
public GeneticController geneticController;
public GeneticDriver geneticDriver;

public Object Genetic;

void Start() {
    if (RaceSelect.SelectedRace == 2) {
        Genetic = geneticDriver;
    } else {
        Genetic = geneticController;
    }

}

void FixedUpdate() {
    float steer = (float)(Genetic.Steering);
    Steering(steer);     

}
```

At the moment It just says, that Object doesn't have a variable called "Steering". What type should Genetic be?

Comment: There's a 99.99999% chance you don't want to be using the `Object` type directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making some assumption here, that both `GeneticController` and `GeneticDriver` implement a `Steering` property?  If so, and especially if they have additional properties and methods in common, the proper way to implement this is to refactor the classes so that they share a common interface.

```
public interface ISteering
{
    float Steering {get; set;}
}
public class GeneticController : ISteering
{
    public float Steering{ get; set; }
}
public class GeneticDriver: ISteering
{
    public float Steering{ get; set; }
}
```

For there you can make your variable `Genetic` a type of `ISteering`.

```
public ISteering Genetic;
```

However, if Steering is the only property they have in common, I recommend you taking a second look at your overall design.  If the two classes share no, or very little, common functions, they probably don't need to share a variable.

Comment: I have tried doing that but for some reason the getter returns 0, even though the setter returns the correct value

Comment: @zarrexx It sounds like that's probably a different question.  I recommend starting a new post, making sure to include your new code.  BTW, don't forget to accept the answer if it properly answers your question!

Comment: @avarient As a new member, it won't let me post another question, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm glad it's working, however it should work without having to be static.  If you do earn enough reputation to post another question, I encourage you to follow up with that.  In any case, good luck in your development!

Comment: because its Unity I already have a base class called monobehaivour therefore I couldnt make another base class ISteering, thats why I had to use static, (I think)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a base class that is derived into your 2 sub-classes?

Something along the lines of:

```
public class BaseClass
{
  public float Steering {get;set;}
}

public class GeneticController : BaseClass
{
}

public class GeneticDriver : BaseClass
{
}
```

then you do the following (and you do not need the cast):

```
BaseClass Genetic

void Start()
{
  if (RaceSelect.SelectedRace == 2)
  {
    Genetic = geneticDriver;
  } else
  {
    Genetic = geneticController;
  }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
  float steer = Genetic.Steering;
  Steering(steer);     
}
```

You could set the BaseClass as an interface also. It depends if you have common functionalities, or not, between you 2 derived classes.

Comment: I have tried doing that but for some reason the getter returns 0, even though the setter returns the correct value